# deleting a object while iterating over array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I've been trying different methods but none of them work but this one seems to be the most simple to do the task that is to **find the entries that are within a group ( idGroup ) wrap them into another array ( inside entries ) and delete the entry that is outside the array it belongs**

```
for(entry in entries) {

if (entries[entry].idGroup) {

    var found = _.find(entries, function (num) { if(num.group == entries[entry].idGroup) { return num; } });

    if(found) {

        entries[_.indexOf(entries, found)].entries.push(entries[entry]);
        delete entries[entry];
        console.log('pushed');

    }else{

        entries.splice(entry,0, { group: entries[entry].idGroup, entries: [entries[entry]] });
        delete entries[entry];
        console.log('created');
    }
}
}
```

This scripting seems to be the most simple of all i've tried but it stills dosen't work; after deleting the current entry it seems to cause a error with the underscore library function _.find "TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined" at the line which _.find is, if i remove the delete operator it works fine.

This is how entries STRUCTURE looks like before

```
[
  {

    id: 0,
    idGroup: 1,
    data: "example"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    idGroup: null,
    data: "example"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    idGroup: 1,
    data: "example"
 }
]
```

and after ( as it should )

```
[
  {

    id: 0,
    group: 1,
    entries: [
     {

       id: 0,
       idGroup: 1,
       data: "example"
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       idGroup: 1,
       data: "example"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    idGroup: null,
    data: "example"
 }
]
```

Comment: This is very confusing. Can you show us what `entries` contains & also tell us in a few words what the expected output should be? or what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Modifying a list you are currently iterating isn't so nice even if underscore weren't a functional library. How about starting from _.groupBy then maybe each or map?

Comment: @istos explained it better, sorry.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want but take a look at some of the set functions that underscore provides e.g. union, intersection and difference.

Comment: @GruffBunny updated it again with how it should look after, sorry hehe, also thanks lossleader i'll take a look but i'd be also grateful if you gave me a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [
  {

    id: 0,
    idGroup: 1,
    data: "example"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    idGroup: null,
    data: "example"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    idGroup: 1,
    data: "example"
 }
];

b = _.groupBy(arr, function(a) {return a.idGroup; });
c = _.toArray(b);
d = _.map(c, function(es, i) { return (es.length > 1) ? {id: i, group: 1 , entries: es} : _.extend({id: i}, es[0]) });
```

Or better if you like

```
_.chain(arr)
  .groupBy(function(a) {return a.idGroup; })
  .toArray()
  .map(function(es, i) { 
    return (es.length > 1) ? {id: i, group: 1 , entries: es} : _.extend({id: i}, es[0]); 
  })
  .value()
```

`groupBy` transforms your original array of Entries to an object whose keys are `idGroup` and values are the array of Entries that matched the criteria.

`toArray` transforms the new object to an array of array of Entries: (`[[Entry]]`)

`map` transforms each array of Entry (`[Entry]`) (that is a member of `[[Entry]]`) to either a new object (with `group: 1` and `entries: [Entry]` or the original Entry but with addition of an `id` field using `extend`).

Comment: Many Thanks! i'll just see if it works fine here before accepting the answer.

Comment: It worked wonderfully! but only with one group, if there's a entry with a idGroup other than 1 it will not be added to a group array, may i ask you if you could solve that?

Comment: I'm sorry but actually could you solve the issue with the multiple groups? because the script in my main question have this ability. ( also i can't seem to fix that myself )

Comment: @Bud can you again post your input and expected output?

Comment: I left the input ( guessing you mean the code ) untouched, i just added another entry with idGroup 2.
`[ { 
    group: 1,
    activities: [ [Object], [Object] ] 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
 idGroup: null,
 data: "example"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
 idGroup: 2,
 data: "example"
  }
]`

Comment: What's your expected output? Where do you expect the Entry with `idGroup: 2` to go?

Comment: oh sorry, i expect to be created `[ { group: 1, activities: [ [Object] ]` even if its just for one entry... welp i just fixed it myself heheh changing `return (es.length > 1)` to `return (as[0].idGroup)` thank you anyways! i still have much to learn on javascript hehehe.

Comment: i just created another question because of certain issues with the code in your answer, also because i better structured my question/issue so it may be more helpful to others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850076/creating-groups-of-objects-inside-array-by-key-value