# Creating array of objects inside array by key/value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I've been trying to do this task but i can't seem to find the "right way" to do it, yesterday i asked here for a fix to the code i was making with pure javascript and i got this answer on my old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830256/deleting-a-object-while-iterating-over-array/) [edited] using underscore;

```
_.chain(arr)
  .groupBy(function(a) {return a.idBox; })
  .toArray()
  .map(function(es, i) { 
    return (es[0].idBox) ? {id: i, group: es[0].idBox, date: es[0].date , entries: es} : _.extend({id: i}, es[0]); 
  })
  .value()
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with it properly with my case, the first issue I've encounter is that it doesn't maintain the original sorting ( by date, the date is retrieved from mysql already sorted desc ) and second it seems that if there's more than one object with idBox: null the first one will make it but the others ( as null ) will not make it to value(). I'm creating a new question because its context/issue itself is pretty different and may be more helpful to others creating a separate question.

input;

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    idbox: null,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    idbox: 1,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    idbox: 1,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    idbox: null,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    idbox: 1,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    idbox: 2,
    date: ""
  }
]
```

expected output;

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    idbox: null,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    box: 1,
    objects: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    idbox: null,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    box: 2,
    objects: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
```

actual output;

```
[
  {
    box: 1,
    date: "",
    objects: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    box: 2,
    date: "",
    objects: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    idbox: null,
    date: ""
  }
]
```

Comment: If you want to preserve ordering, are acting on a sorted array (so that only adjacent items need to be compared) and want to ignore some values (`idbox: null`) in the grouping process, you should not use `_.groupBy`. Implement the grouping yourself, it's quite trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fold` or `reduce` is your friend.

```
arr = your_original_array

_.reduce(arr, function(memo, a) { 
  if (a.idbox == null) {
    memo.push(a);
  } else {
    b = _.find(memo, function(c) { return c.box == a.idbox });
    if (!b) {
      b = {box: a.idbox, objects: []};
      memo.push(b)
    }
    b.objects.push(a)
  }
  return memo
}, []);
```

You can make it faster (if you have thousands of records in your original array):

```
_.reduce(arr, function(memo, a) { 
  if (a.idbox == null) {
    memo.result.push(a);
  } else {
    b = memo.dict[a.idbox]
    if (!b) {
      b = { box: a.idbox, objects: [] };
      memo.result.push(b);
      memo.dict[a.idbox] = b;
    }
    b.objects.push(a);
  }
  return memo;
}, {dict: {}, result: []}).result;
```

`reduce` function operated on every element in your array.

`reduce` function takes two parameters:

- a function that takes the last produced result (Underscore.js call this `memo`) and the current element. It somehow (check the function's body) combines the current element and the last result into a new result. And the new result will be passed as `memo` to the function again with the next item and so on...
- the initial value for memo

Since reduce goes thru your array element by element, this code retain the order without a need for introducing sorting keys.

Comment: Thank you again @homam! This answer looks promising but i'm not being able to reproduce myself, i made arr be the input example on my question but the reduce function doesn't seem to make any change on it.

`var arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    idbox: null,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    idbox: 1,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    idbox: 1,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    idbox: null,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    idbox: 1,
    date: ""
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    idbox: 2,
    date: ""
  }
];

_.reduce(...)        
        console.log(arr);`

Comment: We're using some aspects of functional programming here. In functional programming we don't modify our variables, if you like to change the value of `arr`; just assign it to the result of reduce: `arr = _.reduce(function ...`

Comment: heheh sorry for my silly mistake(s), Thank you homam! exactly what i wanted, also thanks for the faster one ^^